# Cast objects to comparable type

Tags: scala

In Scala. I have two objects of type Any. If it's possible, I'd like to cast the objects to the correct Ordered trait, and then compare them with the < method. Otherwise, I want to throw an exception. Should be simple, but I'm stumped...

Comment: Why not require the objects to be comparable via the type system?

Comment: For various reasons, I don't know the type until runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement this with `Ordering` type class:

```
def compare[T : Ordering : Manifest](a: AnyRef, b: AnyRef) = {
    val c = manifest[T].erasure

    if (c.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass) && c.isAssignableFrom(b.getClass))
        implicitly[Ordering[T]].compare(a.asInstanceOf[T], b.asInstanceOf[T]) 
    else 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong argument type")
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
compare[Date](new Date, new Date)
compare[String]("A", "B")
```

But this code will throw `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
compare[Date]("A", "B")
```

---

### Update

If you really don't know types of objects, that you are trying to compare, then you can use this solution:

```
def compare(a: AnyRef, b: AnyRef) = {
  val c = classOf[Comparable[_]]

  if (c.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass) && c.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass) && a.getClass == b.getClass) {
    a.asInstanceOf[Comparable[AnyRef]].compareTo(b.asInstanceOf[Comparable[AnyRef]])
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incopatible argument types: " + a.getClass.getName + " and " + b.getClass.getName)
  }
}
```

It falls down to Java's `Comparable` interface. Generally scala has 2 traits for this purpose:

- `Ordred` - similar to `Comparable`, but existing classes (like `String` or `Date`) do not implement it, so you can't check it at runtime (at least for these classes)
- `Ordering` - it's type class, and you can't retrieve it at runtime.

From the other hand `Ordered` extends `Comparable` interface, so this solution should also work for all classes that extend `Ordered`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the type of the values until runtime.

Comment: instead of `c.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass)` how about `c.isInstance(a)`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
scala> (i, j) match {                                  
     | case (a: Ordered[Any], b: Ordered[Any]) => a < b
     | case _ => throw new RuntimeException            
     | }
```

Comment: I get:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to scala.math.Ordered

Comment: Right. I suppose your `Any`-values really must be of type `Ordered` for this to work.