# Scala. Checking if a Type is Comparable

Tags: scala, type-conversion, comparable

I have a simple class which takes a generic type, Eg:

```
class SomeClass[T: TypeTag](someVal: T) = {
  def value = someVal
  def columnType = typeOf[T]
}
```

I need to check if [T] is Comparable at runtime (I don't want to require that it's comparable, only check if it is or not). If I have an actual instance of [T] (which i don't), I can do the following which works fine...

```
def canCompareType[T](value: T): Boolean = {
  val compClass = classOf[Comparable[_]]
  compClass.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass)
}
```

But I can't work out how to do this with just the type definition and not actually having an instance of [T] available. I've tried the following thinking that it looks and seems reasonable...

```
def canCompareType[T]: Boolean = {
  val compClass = classOf[Comparable[_]]
  compClass.isAssignableFrom(classOf[T])
}
```

But gives the compile error...

```
Error: class type required but T found : compClass.isAssignableFrom(classOf[T])
```

I found a similar answer here, but it again assumes that I have an instance of [T] available.

[Cast objects to comparable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163884/cast-objects-to-comparable-type)

Any ideas how I can resolve this. I have a feeling that I must be pretty close.

**Update**
I need to be able to check also on value types, so I would want `canCompareType[Int]` to also return true as `100.compareTo(200)` is valid.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
def foo[T: TypeTag] = typeOf[T] match {
    case t if t <:< typeOf[Comparable[_]] => "Comparable"
    case _ => "Not Comparable"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for value types. For example `foo[Int]` will return false, whereas compare is supported on an instance of an Int (or at least knows how to compare and resolves it internally)

Comment: Well, primitive types are not `Comparable`, so that's understandable. If you want it to return true for `Comparable` *or* a primitive type, then add another `case` clause with the guard being `if t <:< typeOf[AnyVal]`